# Email Validating using system.net.mail

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to validate the email. It worked well if only simple text is entered. But when I am entering the partial text say test@ only it doesn't throws exception. Can you please guide me what am I missing.

```
Try
    Dim M As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Txt_Email.Text)
Catch ex As FormatException
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Txt_Email.Text = string.Empty
Exit Sub
End Try
```

Thanks in Adavance

Omer

Comment: When I run your code with just `test@` I get an exception

Comment: Why are you exiting Sub, before ending try if I may ask?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html, where it says `The Official Standard: RFC 5322`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple check, validating the given e-mail adres like:

```
Public Function EmailIsValid(emailaddress As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim address = New MailAddress(emailaddress)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Call it like:

```
Dim result as Boolean = EmailIsValid(Txt_Email.Text)
```

result will be filled with true if this is a valid e-mailaddress and will be filled with false if it isn't. But, there are better ways checking if an emailaddress is valid. Perhaps using Regex.

The way I mentioned above isn't that good, since manipulating code using `try/catch` is a bad idea.

A Regex way of doing this can be found here: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)